# I need some help to convert a little code from C to Java

Tags: java, c, code-translation

I have a question and this one will be quick. I just need to convert this little snippet from C to Java.

Here is the C code

[image: C code]
<sub>(source: [cip-labs.net](http://www.cip-labs.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/benford_c_sum.png))</sub>

Here is what I have done so far. I put $$$$ sings where I was super confused.

```
float benford10(int n, int d){
float j = $$$$$$(10, n-1), s=0, i;


for(i=$$$$($$$(10,(n-2))); i<=j-1; i++){
s+= $$$(1+(1/((i*10)+d)));
}
return s;
}
```

Can anyone help me translate the code from C to java? I would appreciate it so much. Thanks!

Comment: you will find all function in Java Math class . http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Answer (score 5):

Most of the functions in C's `math.h` header have equivalents as static methods in Java's [`java.lang.Math`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class:

```
pow => Math.pow
floor => Math.floor
log10 => Math.log10
```

Answer (score 2):

import [java.lang.math](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html), the functions are rather similar.